# Why is there white space at the end of a DIV

Tags: html, css

[image]

Why isn't the DIV with blue background expanding to fill the page?
Also, the parent DIV has black background which is not shown, how come?

I included my developer tool preview

Comment: Please show us what you have done and if you can a fiddle too..

Comment: It is generated by ASP.net so hard to do a Fiddle.

Comment: ok then please post the relevant markup and css

Comment: Too difficult to see any of that code, but your best bet is to use your developer tools to see what element the white space is part of, and then play around with the styling of that element.

Comment: I will post everything in a document and post the link here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your preview, I can see the there are 3 div's in the same level. (the blue is one of them)

1. div has 19% width
2. div has 59% width
3. div (blue) has 20% width

19+59+20 = 98% which tells you that the divs will never fillout the width of the browser.

You either have to make sure the total of the divs gives you 100% and also make sure that nothing inside the blue div have a specified width that exceeds the calculated 20%

**Update 1**

The second question about the black div.
The divs inside are floating which makes the outer div not not clearing them if its not told. Therefor you either need a clear or adding the overflow css style to the outer div.

**clear div**

```
<outer div>
    <red div></div>
    <green div></div>
    <blue div></div>
    <div style="clear"></div> <!-- this div -->
</div>
```

**overflow**

```
<outer div style="overflow:auto;"> <!-- added style -->
    <red div></div>
    <green div></div>
    <blue div></div>
</div>
```